# Build Fail for build.xml regarding classpath in java

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, weblogic

This build.xml is an extract from the tutorial from **Java EE Development with Eclipse by Deepak Vohra** In which we are attempting to present data on a **Jasper Report-4.7.0** Spreadsheet from a **Oracle Database 12c** using **Oracle WebLogic server 12c**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
WebLogic build file
-->
<project name="JasperReports" default="deploy" basedir=".">
<property name="web.module" value="${basedir}/WebContent" />
<property name="weblogic.home" value=" C:/Oracle/Middleware/" />
<property name="weblogic.server" value="${weblogic.home}/
wlserver_12.1/server" />
<property name="build.dir" value="${basedir}/build" />
<property name="weblogic.domain.dir"
value="${weblogic.home}/user_projects/domains/base_domain1" />
<property name="deploy.dir"
value="${weblogic.domain.dir}/autodeploy" />
<path id="classpath">
<fileset dir="${weblogic.home}/modules">
<include name="*.jar" />
</fileset>
<fileset dir="${weblogic.server}/lib">
<include name="*.jar" />
</fileset>
<fileset dir="${weblogic.domain.dir}/lib">
<include name="*.jar" />
</fileset>
<pathelement location="${build.dir}" />
</path>
<property name="build.classpath" refid="classpath" />
<target name="prepare">
<mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
</target>
<target name="war" depends="prepare">
<war warfile="${build.dir}/jasperreports.war">
<fileset dir="WebContent">
<include name="*.jsp" />
</fileset>
<fileset dir="WebContent">
<include name="catalog.xml" />
</fileset>
<fileset dir="WebContent">
<include name="WEB-INF/web.xml" />
</fileset>
<fileset dir="WebContent">
<include name="WEB-INF/lib/*.jar" />
</fileset>
</war>
</target>
<target name="deploy" depends="war">
<copy file="${build.dir}/jasperreports.war" todir="${deploy.dir}"
/>
</target>
<target name="clean">
<delete file="${build.dir}/jasperreports.war" />
</target>
</project>
```

Its showing the error

**BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\abc\workspace\PDFExcelReports\WebContent\build.xml:27: C:\Users\abc\workspace\PDFExcelReports\WebContent\ C:\Oracle\Middleware\modules does not exist.**

and showing error on this line

```
<property name="build.classpath" refid="classpath" />
```

tried to replace classpath with the path of jasper report jar file but didn't worked

Do inform if more details required

Comment: put an echo and try to print whats the value of classpath. I don't think the error is at the line you mentioned

Comment: does it has to be written in startweblogic.cmd file or somewhere else

Comment: which target did u run?

Comment: build.xml using Ant Build 3

Comment: you don't run build xml, you run targets. In this case it runs deploy as it is defined as default - default="deploy"

Comment: so what do i have to fix...i am confused

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at this location :

```
<fileset dir="${weblogic.home}/modules">
```

Firstly, remove the extra space in the path

```
<property name="weblogic.home" value=" C:/Oracle/Middleware/" />
```

I don't find it in the code you pasted by I feel somewhere you are prefixing `${basedir}` to `weblogic.home`

Comment: remove extra space and put value="C:/Oracle/Middleware/". Save and Refresh the buildfile if you are using eclipse. Let me know if you see an error

Comment: mailing me wont help as I dont have weblogic on my system